# meta tag scraper

Tags: php, meta-tags

I'm trying to get meta tag information for each page on a particular site, preferable in a txt file.  What's the simplest way of doing this?

(I mean besides going to each page one by one, viewing source and then copying and pasting the tags, which would be the simplest but also wouldn't be any fun)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a tool like this: [Scraping Links With PHP](http://www.merchantos.com/makebeta/php/scraping-links-with-php/#php_dom), or you could use fopen to open the pages and then regunales expressions may take out the tags [html tags](http://www.roscripts.com/PHP_regular_expressions_examples-136.html).